# Writing SQL function but its not working as desired

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

| Bonus |  | Workers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 90 |  | 1 |
| 90 |  | 2 |
| 50 |  | 3 |
| 40 |  | 4 |
| 30 |  | 5 |
| 20 |  | 6 |
| 10 |  | 7 |

Let's say that I have a column shown above(it might be listed in horizontal order sorry for the mistake) I have written a user-defined function and want to multiply the bonus by 3 but there are two same values in my column. I want the function to detect two workers who have the same bonus amount and print 'two workers have same bonus amount' who can help to get out of this?

```
Create function newfunction
(
    @bonus as integer
    , @workers as integer
)
returns varchar(25)
as
begin
    declare @equality as integer 
    declare @returnvalue as varchar(25)

    Select @equality = Bonus
    from Employeestbl
    Where Workers = @workers

    If @equality = @Bonus set @returnvalue = 'there is an error'

    return @returnvalue
end

select *, dbo.newfunction(employeestbl.bonus,employeestbl.workers)
from Employeestbl
```

Comment: Yeah exactly Bonus is the column name of a database table.İ have written the script on MSSQL

Comment: I've edited the question and added the SQL-Server tag. Can you post the script that you have written? In order to do what you want, you would need a "workers" column - can you edit your question and include that also

Comment: Yeap there is workers column as well

Comment: You might wonder what is the point of writing @equality=@bonus .I wrote these variables by thinking that If there are same values in the column Sql will understand if I make these variables equal to each other

Comment: But instead it brought me all the values with a 'there is an error' in a new column next to them.That is not what I desire.I  would rather want this @returnvalue ='there is an error' only appears in front of the workers having same amount of bonus

Comment: Please if someone has solved this or found a way of doing write here to notify me because it is very urgent

Comment: @AlisahibQadimov please read why [saying a question is urgent is not OK on this site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: You shouldn't use a function for this. A `GROUP BY` query is what you need.

Comment: Why what is the reason ?

Comment: Your function and usage is simply utter nonsense. You set `@equality` with the value of Bonus that is retrieved using `@workers`. So that logic will find the same value supplied as the parameter ALWAYS. But it seems you try to do too many things with your function - it makes no sense to use a string as a return value and set it to "error message" OR a piece of useful information.

Comment: What do you recommend ?

Comment: Sounds like you actually need either a window/analytical function or a subquery

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`set returnvalue`  this is a variable and must be `set @returnvalue` you have a syntax error in function.

Comment: Okay,I corrected my error

Comment: Then what should i do

Answer (score 0):

*I want the function to detect two workers who have the same bonus amount and print 'two workers have same bonus amount*

This query will find that:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Bonus, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY Bonus HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) PRINT 'two workers have same bonus amount'
```

*want to multiply the bonus by 3*

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Bonus = Bonus * 3
```

Assuming you don't want to apply the bonus if two bonuses are the same, heres a script to do that:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT Bonus, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY Bonus HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'two workers have same bonus amount'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable SET Bonus = Bonus * 3
END
```

Comment: Thank you very much everything works perfectly now.Do you think I can use this query on user defined function?

Comment: User defined functions cant update.  Use it in a stored procedure instead.

Comment: Big thanks I got everything crystal clear

Comment: Glad to hear it. If the answer helped please tick it.

Comment: I don't understand why would you accept the completely misleading and unhelpful answer rather than this one?